# How do I check node_modules directory for unnecessary packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, package-managers

My node_modules has packages that are not listed in my package.json's dependencies, so I'm guessing that those packages are dependencies of my dependencies. How would I be able to check this? I want to make sure that there aren't any unnecessary packages in my node_modules directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dependency list won't take too long to reinstall, a simple option is a table-flip: remove the `node_modules` directory entirely and run `npm install` to re-create it.

If you don't want to do that, you can try tools that inspect your dependencies, like [depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck) as @sagar-gopale suggests in their answer.

Related: Run `npm -v` to find out if you are running npm v2 or v3. Like @cartant says in their answer, with v3, your `node_modules` directory will be maximally flat, which means things that used to appear as subdirectories of other modules (when installed with npm v2) will now appear at the top level of `node_modules` itself. That may be the reason you see more modules than you expect.

Comment: I've done the first option of table-flipping but when I run dep check it still shows a lot of "unused dependencies" that I definitely know I'm using. What is depcheck basing this off of? I also did `npm install -g depcheck react jsx` because I'm building that kind of app, but if I using es6, do I have include that too? what does it mean for it to have the syntax support for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NPM 3, you will likely see a large number of modules that you were not expecting to see in the `node_modules` directory, as NPM 3 flattens the dependency hierarchy.

Whichever version you are using, if you run the `npm list` command, NPM should highlight any extraneous modules that are not required.

Comment: is there anyway to unflatten the dependency hierarchy so it just shows what i need?

Comment: If you run the `npm list --depth=0` command, it should list only the root level modules. Typically, you will add modules as dependencies to your `package.json`, running `npm install` to install whatever you've added. If you need to know whether or not you've actually used/required a dependency, a tool like `depcheck` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout this package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck

Answer (score 1):

Since packages can require other packages, just because there are packages in the node_modules folder that don't exist in your packages.json file doesn't mean they aren't needed by one of your specified packages.

If you run an `npm prune` command on the root directory of your solution it will read the dependency tree and remove the packages that are truly no longer needed.